# Why am I getting a fancy image viewer in VS Code with various buttons like zoom and rotate?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode in windows. After a update, my image viewer becomes a gallery-like version, like image1:[new version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20atY.jpg)
However, I prefer old view(same with ssh to ubuntu server), which, an image is just an image, whithout any gallery function, like this[old and linux version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnzD0.jpg).
How should I change my setting? Or how to achieve this?

I search the Internet, but I can not find a formal discussion. I expect to know how to set my vscode.

Comment: Were you using an extension for this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was found by doing an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to be a feature-contribution of the [`cweijan.vscode-office`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-office) extension.

If you don't want this feature of that extension, you can either disable the extension completely, or you can probably look into disabling just that part of it for image files by putting some variation of the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) to go back to [VS Code's builtin image custom "editor"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/media-preview/src/imagePreview) (for more info about custom editors:

```json
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.png": "imagePreview.previewEditor",
}
```

For more info about custom editors in VS Code in general, see [the related API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors).